# HTML CSS - Creating spaces to the right of Input

Tags: html, css

I made a search box like this:

[image]

I put a search icon. When typing to Input, the image of the icon stays behind. How can I solve this?

`style.css`:

```
.headmenu-right {
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.headmenu-right>input {
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.searchIcon {
    background-image: url("/img/search.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: right;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Please show us your HTML structure. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @CNASIR maybe not the place to advertise your course (I see you have made the same comment elsewhere)

Answer (score 1):

just add a padding-right of 50px or whatever you want to the input